# how can i append templated data to a specific div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jquery templating plugin and want to append the object data to the id #store but Im not sure how to do this.

Basically the data is captured using `.template('playerTemp', data);` but Im not sure how this can be added to `$('#store').append();` ?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that the jQuery template plugin is no longer being developed or maintained.  So if you are going to be using it heavily, read this first http://www.borismoore.com/2011/10/jquery-templates-and-jsviews-roadmap.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must say that I'm not fimilar with the `template` plugin, but you can use the `appendTo` function:

```
newElements.appendTo($('#store'));
```

So if  you get the data with: `.template('playerTemp', data)` as you wrote, You can append it like:

```
.template('playerTemp', data).appendTo($('#store'));
```

`appendTo` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

> Description: Insert every element in the set of matched elements to the end of the target.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This compiles the template
$("#yourTemplateID").template('playerTemp');

// This appends it to a specific element
$.tmpl("playerTemp", data).appendTo("#store");
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like:

```
$('#store').append($(this).template('playerTemp',data));
```

I don't know what object the "template" is envoking so I just used "this".